# Retrieve and store two values from SQL Server into c#

Tags: c#, sql

Here is what I am trying to achieve. I want to get two values from the same row in the same table and store them into two variables. I am doing this in MVC.

Here is what I am doing :

```
SqlCommand amd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Value1] FROM [ExampleTable] where Ad_name=@adname", con);
SqlCommand bmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Value2] FROM [ExampleTable] where Ad_name=@adname", con);
amd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adname", aname);
bmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adname", aname);
imgpath1 = amd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
imgpath2 = bmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

But here is what I want:

```
SqlCommand amd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Value1] AND [Value2] FROM [ExampleTable] where Ad_name=@adname", con);
amd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adname", aname);
imgpath1 = Value1;
imgpath2 = Value2;
```

How can I achieve that without writing multiple queries? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the method of SqlCommand [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that return a [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using(var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Value1], [Value2] FROM [ExampleTable] where Ad_name=@adname", con))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adname", aname);

    using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            imgpath1 = reader[0];
            imgpath2 = reader[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second SQL command isn't going to work, and if you want to values you wont be able to do a scalar query...

Try:

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Value1], [Value2] FROM [ExampleTable] where Ad_name=@adname", con);
```

And add the parameter.

Then you can

```
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

and get the values by

```
reader["[Value1]"];
reader["[Value2]"];
```

Essentially, doing a scalar query is meant for queries which only return a single value.

Answer (score 1):

You call the database just one time with the method [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx).
Notice how the single columns required are listed after the SELECT separated by a comma.
This is the common basic syntax required for a [SELECT statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp)
This method returns a DataReader that you can use to get single values of a row.
I suppose that your query returns just one record, so, the loop is not strictly necessary.

```
SqlCommand amd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Value1], [Value2] FROM [ExampleTable] where Ad_name=@adname", con);
amd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adname", aname);
SqlDataReader reader = amd.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{
    imgPath1 = reader[0].ToString();
    imgPath2 = reader[1].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use comma as separator between retrieved columns, use GetOrdinal to avoid constant numbers like [1] and [2].

```
const string ColumnOne = "ColumnOne";
const string ColumnTwo = "ColumnTwo";
var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("select [VALUE1] as " + ColumnOne + ", [VALUE2] as " + ColumnTwo + " from table", sqlConn);
var sqlCmdReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
if (sqlCmdReader.Read())
    {
    var resultOne= sqlCmdReader.GetString(sqlCmdReader.GetOrdinal(ColumnOne));
    var resultTwo= sqlCmdReader.GetString(sqlCmdReader.GetOrdinal(ColumnTwo ));
}
```